# How to add ServletContextListener in embedded tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat8, servletcontextlistener

I have a simple application with embedded tomcat. And I trying to do some initialization work and I need JNDI resources.

I trying to do it in `ServletContextListener.contextInitialized`.

When I add `ServletContextListener` before `tomcat.start()`, `context.getServletContext()` returns `null`.

If I doing it after `tomcat.start()`, I got an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Listeners cannot be added to context [] as the context has been initialised
```

This is launcher code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Tomcat server = new Tomcat();
    server.setPort(8080);

    Context context = server.addContext("", Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().toString());

    Tomcat.addServlet(context, "hello", new HelloServlet());
    context.addServletMappingDecoded("/", "hello");

    ContextResource resource = buildResource(
        H2_DATA_SOURCE_NAME,
        DataSource.class.getName(),
        h2DatasourceProperties()
    );

    context.getNamingResources().addResource(resource);
    context.getServletContext().addListener(DataBaseSchemaInit.class);

    server.start();
    server.getServer().await();
}
```

How can I add `ServletContextListener` in embedded tomcat v.8.5.28 ?

Comment: i don't see enough code here.

Comment: @DieNerd I've added code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it using `ServletContainerInitializer`.

```
StandardContext context = buildContext(tomcat);
...
context.addServletContainerInitializer(new DataBaseInitializer(DATA_BASE_SCHEMA), null);
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a working example at [github.jakarta](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.tst.tomcat.embedded).

I just used jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebListener and contextInitialized is triggered.

I degraded from jakarta to javax for your use case [github.javax](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.tst.tomcat.embedded.gwt)